# AttributeError 'NoneType' has no attribute 'name' on Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'll be very gratefull if someone could help me! I'm having some problems when try to access my dashboard page on my django project. The error is saying:

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

............

My view.py file contains the function "dashboard_view":

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    


........



    plano_atual_usuario, preco_atual, conversas_a_pagar = user.current_user_plan_price_and_conversas_a_pagar(STANDART_PERIOD)

    numero_de_pedidos = pedidos.count()
    numero_de_conversas = conversas.count()
    numero_de_conversas_do_periodo = conversas_do_periodo.count()
    if numero_de_conversas > 0:
        taxa_conversao = round((numero_de_pedidos / numero_de_conversas) * 100, 2)
    else:
        taxa_conversao = 0.0
    
    dias_para_pagamento = user.days_to_next_payment(STANDART_PERIOD)
    data_proximo_pagamento = today + timedelta(days=dias_para_pagamento)
    nome_do_plano = plano_atual_usuario.name -----> Problem is here!!!
    minimo_conversas_plano_atual = plano_atual_usuario.minimo_conversas
    limite_conversas_plano_atual = plano_atual_usuario.maximo_conversas
    valor_por_conversa_do_plano_atual = preco_atual
    gasto_atual_do_periodo = conversas_a_pagar * valor_por_conversa_do_plano_atual

    limite_atual_conversas = int(user.conversation_limit_set_by_user)

    
.........
    

    context = {
        'user' : user,
        'conversas': conversas,
        'pedidos' : pedidos,
        'dados_clientes' : dados_clientes,
        'numero_de_pedidos' : numero_de_pedidos,
        'numero_de_conversas' : numero_de_conversas,
        'numero_de_conversas_do_periodo' : numero_de_conversas_do_periodo,
        'taxa_conversao' : taxa_conversao,
        'dias_para_pagamento' : dias_para_pagamento,
        'nome_do_plano' : nome_do_plano,
        'gasto_atual_do_periodo' : gasto_atual_do_periodo,
        'valor_por_conversa_do_plano_atual' : valor_por_conversa_do_plano_atual,
        'minimo_conversas_plano_atual' : minimo_conversas_plano_atual,
        'limite_conversas_plano_atual' : limite_conversas_plano_atual,
        'data_proximo_pagamento' : data_proximo_pagamento,
        'conversas_a_pagar' : conversas_a_pagar,
        'userIsPremium' : user.userIsPremium(),
        'limite_atual_conversas': limite_atual_conversas,
        'conversas_per_months': json.dumps(conversas_per_months),
        'conversas_per_days': json.dumps(conversas_per_days),
    }

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

I already make all migrations and I checked that the database is ok. I've also tried to post some "prints" to try to find this error but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: What is your assurance that `plano_atual_usuario, preco_atual, conversas_a_pagar = user.current_user_plan_price_and_conversas_a_pagar(STANDART_PERIOD)` gives you a tuple with actual data? From the error it is clear that `plano_atual_usuario` is `None`

Comment: Share your models. The error says that `plano_atual_usuario` does not exist, thus you cannot access its `name` attribute.